# conda install -c bioconda simlord | UnsatisfiedError

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, conda

Following this [tutorial](https://bitbucket.org/genomeinformatics/simlord/src/master/) and two [installation steps](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/simlord), I want to run `SimLoRD`.

On `Ubuntu 18.04`, using a `Python 3.9` venv:

```
conda install -c bioconda simlord
UnsatisfiedError
```

[image: Terminal output]

I have tried this on `Windows` and `Linux` with different versions of `Anaconda` and `Python` without luck.

---

Suggested `pip install simlord==1.0.4` via. `Windows 10`:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

[image: Windows pip install error]

Comment: This issue is a bit perplexing. Looking at the `setup.py` for simlord, a minimum of 3.4 is required. See: https://bitbucket.org/genomeinformatics/simlord/src/master/setup.py. The PyPI package says Python 3, so it should work. I suspect it's the `bioconda` which does not have the latest version. You really need to provide the full list of outputs. Something else is requiring specific python version.

Comment: Looking at `conda` repo for the list of builds available, I do not see py39: https://anaconda.org/bioconda/simlord/files

Comment: Oh, py39 was just the name I gave to the environment

Comment: Please also try avoiding image uploads. Those are not searchable. Copy and paste the messages.

Comment: I will append error messages

Comment: Append all of it from the `pip install`

Answer (score 1):

[Solution at BioStars](https://www.biostars.org/p/9463133/#9463299). TLDR; `Python 3.6.5` is the most recent stable version for installing and running `SimLoRD`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will entirely work for your setup as I don't know what your full analysis workflow is and what other dependencies you have, but you can install `simlord` via `pip`:

```
(py39) dbell30@dbell30-VirtualBox:~$ pip install simlord==1.0.4
```

If it is successful, check the output of `pip list`

Comment: I will try this in 23 hours time (8am BST). As my Ubuntu VM is on my uni servers

Comment: Wait, I tried it via. Anaconda Prompt on my local Windows 10 PC but with an Error. I will upload image in post

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new environment. Something like

```bash
conda create -n simlord -c conda-forge -c bioconda -c defaults simlord
```

Note the three channels here is [the recommended channel priority](https://bioconda.github.io/user/install.html#set-up-channels) for Bioconda-based installations.